# JS not toggling divs on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is that when I check the checkbox the divs don't toggle. They don't show up for some reason. Can someone identify a problem please ?

This is my html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="Value1" name="ranged" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" class="ranged" /> Ranged
<input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="Value1" name="meele" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" class="meele" /> Melee
<input type="checkbox" id="Check3" value="Value1" name="magic" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" class="magic" /> Magic

<div id="wizards" hidden>
    <img src="/img/chars/char1.png">
    <img src="/img/chars/char2.png">
    <img src="/img/chars/char3.png">
    <img src="/img/chars/char4.png">
    <img src="/img/chars/char5.png">
    <img src="/img/chars/char6.png">
    <img src="/img/chars/char7.png">
    <img src="/img/chars/char8.png">
</div>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectOnlyThis(id) {
        for (var i = 1;i <= 3; i++)
        {
            document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked = false;
        }
        document.getElementById(id).checked = true;   
    }

    $('.magic').on('click', function(){
        $('#wizards').toggle("fast");
        $('#melees').slideUp('fast');
        $('#rangers').slideUp('fast');
    });
</script>
```

This is what I'm loading:

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Any reason for the mix of vanilla JS and jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 I don't get any

Comment: @Andy probably... How could I fix this ?

Comment: Choose one or the other I guess...?

Comment: If this is your full code, then where are `#melees`, `#rangers` ? If not, then please post your full code

Comment: @rv7 It's just two more same divs as `wizards`

Comment: So you are reinventing radio buttons?

Comment: I tested your code, and it runs so..... not sure what your issue is.

Comment: @epascarello I don't even get it why this doesnt work. It seems to work fine in older project...

Comment: Impossible to tell if the code above works.....not much we can do but guess.... Maybe there is something else going on. Is the code dynamic? Does the functions get triggered? Any errors in console? console.log() is your friend...

Comment: It may sound silly, but are you loading jQuery? are there other instances of it or other libraries being loaded? just trying to cover stuff...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Updated the question with libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="Value1" name="ranged" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" class="ranged" /> Ranged
<input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="Value1" name="meele" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" class="meele" /> Melee
<input type="checkbox" id="Check3" value="Value1" name="magic" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" class="magic" /> Magic

<div id="rangers" hidden>
  Rangers
</div>
<div id="melees" hidden>
  Melees
</div>
<div id="wizards" hidden>
  Wizards
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectOnlyThis(id) {
        for (var i = 1;i <= 3; i++)
        {
            document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked = false;
        }
        document.getElementById(id).checked = true;   
    }

    $('input').on('click', function(){
        $('#wizards').slideUp("fast");
        $('#melees').slideUp('fast');
        $('#rangers').slideUp('fast');
        
        var index = $(this).index() - 1;
        $('div').eq(index).slideDown('fast');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Problem was something with my styles... There were no errors but probably the images are itself under my bg or something.. strange

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.magic').on('change', function(){
        $('#wizards').toggle("fast");
        $('#melees').slideUp('fast');
        $('#rangers').slideUp('fast');
    });
```

Comment: Which divs you are talking about ?

Comment: You have onChange event when you click on element with class magic